# Python re.match not finding characters in the middle of the string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of website links that are exactly the same except for the changing year, which is what I am trying to find. I'm using re.match to try and find it since the string is the exact same except for the 4 characters (20xx). For some reason it is only returning None though, and I don't know why.

I have tried to use other re methods such as findall and fullmatch, but it doesn't help.

```
state_links = ["https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2009/index.htm",
               "https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2010/index.htm",
               "https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2011/index.htm",
               "https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2012/index.htm",
               "https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2013/index.htm",
               "https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2014/index.htm",
               "https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2015/index.htm",
               "https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2016/index.htm"]

for link in state_links:
   year = re.match(r"https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/(.*)/index.htm", link)

   print(year)
```

Comment: For me it is working fine, check it again.

Comment: You should escape all the `.` characters in the regexp. But it shouldn't make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example as shown works, printing a series of `re.Match` instances.  (Though, the `.` is not doing what you think it's doing, and it may be sounder practice to use `\d{4}` inside the capturing group.  A plain `.` is  a pattern for any character; you probably want a literal period, `\.`.)

Regardless, if your links are always that cleanly formatted, you can also use a just a `str` method here:

```
>>> [int(i.rsplit("/", 2)[-2]) for i in state_links]
[2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
```

This splits each link into 3 parts, where each intermediate element will look like:

```
>>> state_links[0].rsplit("/", 2)
['https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps', '2009', 'index.htm']
```

The `[-2]` indexer then takes the year component.

Answer (score 0):

as @Drubio indicated, your regex pattern is correct.  However, check your code.  The following works:

```
regex = r"https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/(\d{4})/index.htm"
years = re.finditer(regex, state_links, re.MULTILINE)
for year in years:    
    for j in range(0, len(year.groups())):
        j  += 1       
        print ("{year}".format(year = year.group(j))) 

Output
## 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
```

Credit to @Brad for `\d{4}` suggestion/correction and also `.split` option